# I am trying, and failing to import Pygame on Atom, even though it works on IDLE

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

sorry, I am completely new to coding, and am trying to install Pygame on Mac. I have it installed, and on IDLE it works fine, however, when I try to import it on Atom, it says:
ImportError: No module named pygame
I've been looking for a solution for a while now, and can't seem to find anything, was wondering if anyone on hear could help?

Comment: Can you share the code with the import statement? When you run `pip freeze` can you verify it was installed?

If you are using a virtualenv it looks like there are some known issues documented here - https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted#Mac%20installation

Comment: I haven't written any code with Pygame so far, I was just trying to import it, and then it gave me an error, and where's mould I run " pip freeze"? in the terminal? Also the aliens game at (python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens) worked for me, so I believe that that is evidence

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue too below can be few of the reasons/solutions:

1. you might be using pygame through anaconda instead pip, try doing "pip install pygame" in windows cmd to fix it.
2. u must also add atom's bin folder through its directory to your path. you can easily find online how you can add stuff to path and you'll find the bin folder where you have installed atom.

Comment: I have installed Pygame through pip3, so I know that it's not that. However, the other one seems like it could be the problem, but I don't really understand what to do. Sorry, my knowledge of terminology is very low, is it a package that I need to install?